# How to do that fields not initialization?

Tags: asp.net

how to do that every time s_Sort not update SortDirection.Desc

```
private SortDirection s_Sort = SortDirection.Desc;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSort.Text = S_Sort.ToString();//every time == SortDirection.Desc - this is bad!
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ShowTree();

            Validate();
        }
}
```

Need

```
public void btnSortUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        S_Sort = SortDirection.Asc;
    }
    public void btnSortDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        S_Sort = SortDirection.Desc;
    }
```

but after SortDirection.Desc is bad

Comment: If you don't wan't it to be SortDirection.Desc then don't assign it every time... what does it need to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is a problem of the ASP.NET lifecycle. Every time a postback happens (for example, when btnSortUp or btnSortDown is clicked), a new instance of your page is created, i.e., S_Sort is reinitialized to Desc. If you want to persist the value between postbacks, you can store it in the viewstate, for example, by encapsulating it in a private property:

```
private SortDirection S_Sort {
    get { return (SortDirection)(ViewState["S_Sort"] ?? SortDirection.Desc); }
    set { ViewState["S_Sort"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: And I can save in ViewState big array ?

Comment: @simply: Yes, you can, but be aware that the viewstate (a) is sent back and forth between the client and the server on *every* postback, and (b) can be modified by a malicious user. So, storing big stuff in the viewstate can lead to performance problems. For such stuff, the `Session` might be a better place (or the `Cache`, if the array is the same for all clients).

Comment: +1 pulling the right answer out of that question deserves more than 2 votes.